# Lazy Evaluation: forward operations to deferred value

Tags: python, python-2.7, lazy-evaluation, getattr

I have implemented classes for lazily evaluating configurations that are dumped to JSON. No problem there, just extend the encoder to actively evaluate the classes using a specific protocol (fixed method/property).

```
class DeferredCall(object):
  """Call that is evaluated lazyly"""
  def __init__(self, func, *func_args, **func_kwargs):
    self.func = func
    self.func_args = func_args
    self.func_kwargs = func_kwargs

  def resolve(self):  # called by JSON encoder
    return self.func(*self.func_args, **self.func_kwargs)

 a = DeferredCall(lambda: 1)
 a # gives <[module].DeferredCall at 0x1e99410>
 a.resolve() # gives 1
```

Now, with great power comes users that want more power. Namely, doing operations with the classes directly instead of the values they stand for. According to the [python data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#data-model), this should be as simple as implementing the magic methods, such as `__add__`, `__len__` etc.

Adding

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return self.resolve() + other
```

or

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return self.resolve().__add__(other)
```

will correctly give me `a + 3 == 4`.

Implementing *all* magic methods a bit too much, though. So I tried using `__getattr__`

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
  return getattr(self.resolve(), item)
```

which works for `a.__mul__(3) == 3` but blow up for `a * 3 == 3` with `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'DeferredCall' and 'int'`.

So is there any *other* way to forward operators to the wrapped values? Ideally without venturing to programmatically writing code or the hassle of `__getattribute__`.

Comment: As I understand it, the way Python looks up magic method attributes won't allow you to implement them dynamically like this - for `x + y` if `x.__add__` isn't defined `y.__radd__(x)` gets called, hence the error you're seeing. Also, note that you aren't dealing with cases where `other` is *also* a `DeferredCall`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Technically, `x.__add__` is defined - I can use it directly. As far as I understand the docs, both objects being `DeferredCall`s should work as the left hand side will resolve to `x.resolve().__add__(other)`, which will fail but trigger `other.resolve().__add__(x.resolve())` since x has already been resolved in the call to `__add__`. Obviously, at least the first is not correct somehow, but I haven't found any information on how operators resolve attributes.

Comment: You can access the method directly, but you can demonstrate for yourself that `x + y` will not call `__getattr[ibute]__` on `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution in case anybody else needs it. Most "builtin" actions such as `*` or `len` will not use `__getattr[ibute]__`, by design.

I've settled for creating the methods programmatically

```
class DeferredCall(object):
  def __init__(self, func, *func_args, **func_kwargs):
    self.func = func
    self.func_args = func_args
    self.func_kwargs = func_kwargs

  def resolve(self):
    return self.func(*self.func_args, **self.func_kwargs)

  # magic must be resolved explicitly
  # self other - resolve in reflected order to allow other to resolve as well
  for so_magic in [("lt", "gt"), ("le", "ge"), ("eq", "eq"), ("ne", "ne"), ("add", "radd"), ("sub", "rsub"), ("mul", "rmul"), ("div", "rdiv"), ("truediv", "rtruediv"), ("floordiv", "rfloordiv"), ("mod", "rmod"), ("divmod", "rdivmod"), ("pow", "rpow"), ("lshift", "rlshift"), ("rshift", "rrshift"), ("and", "rand"), ("xor", "rxor"), ("or", "ror")]:
    for func_name, refl_name in [(so_magic[0], so_magic[1]), (so_magic[1], so_magic[0])]:
      exec("def __%(fname)s__(self, other):\n\ttry:\n\t\tres = other.__%(rname)s__(self.resolve())\n\t\tif res == NotImplemented:\n\t\t\traise AttributeError\n\texcept AttributeError:\n\t\tres = self.resolve().__%(fname)s__(other)\n\treturn res" % {"fname": func_name, "rname": refl_name})

  # regular magic - immutable only
  for magic in ("str", "nonzero", "unicode", "getattr", "call", "len", "getitem", "missing", "iter", "reversed", "contains", "getslice", "neg", "pos", "abs", "invert", "complex", "int", "long", "float", "oct", "hex", "index"):
    exec("def __%(fname)s__(self, *args, **kwargs):\n\treturn self.resolve().__%(fname)s__(*args, **kwargs)" % {"fname": magic})
```

Basically, the magic methods must be split into two categories: self-contained ones and contextual ones.

The self-contained ones are created straightforward, resolving the call and executing the magic method. For example, `len` is resolved as:

```
def __len__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  return self.resolve().__len__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The contextual ones must invert the call, e.g. "greater than" `other` actually checks if `other` is "smaller than" `self`. This is required if both objects are deferred calls, allowing `other` to resolve itself as well; otherwise, a `TypeError` would be raised by many methods. The direct evaluation is only used if `other` does not have the inverted version.

```
def __gt__(self, other):
  try:
    res = other.__lt__(self.resolve())
    if res == NotImplemented:
      raise AttributeError
  except AttributeError:
    res = self.resolve().__gt__(other)
  return res
```

Some of the calls could probably be implemented more efficiently, since python uses some tricks (which is precisely where my problem comes from in the first place). For example, multiplying could exploit commutativity:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
  """self * other"""
  return other * self.resolve()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a meta-class to dynamically generate all the functions. You can either explicitly specify the names all the methods you wish to implement or inspect an existing class and create the methods with the same names on your class.

For example, creating all the methods that `int` implements:

```python
def _wrapper(func_name):
    def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.resolve()
        func = getattr(value, func_name, None)
        if func is None:
            raise AttributeError(func_name)
        resolved_args = [
            arg.resolve() if isinstance(arg, DeferredCall) else arg
            for arg in args
        ]
        resolved_kwargs = {
            arg_name: arg.resolve() if isinstance(arg, DeferredCall) else arg
            for arg_name, arg in kwargs.items()
        }
        return func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
    return method


class DeferredCallMetaclass(type):
    NON_WRAPPED_METHODS = (
        "__class__",
        "__class_getitem__",
        "__delattr__",
        "__dir__",
        "__doc__",
        "__getattribute__",
        "__getstate__",
        "__init__",
        "__init_subclass__",
        "__new__",
        "__repr__",
        "__setattr__",
        "__subclasshook__",
    )

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs, **additional_kwargs):
        # Find all the routines belonging to the int class and create corresponding
        # wrapped methods on DeferredCall (except for the methods listed above).
        for attr, _ in getmembers(int, predicate=isroutine):
            if (
                attr not in attrs
                and attr not in DeferredCallMetaclass.NON_WRAPPED_METHODS
            ):
                attrs[attr] = _wrapper(attr)
        return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs, **additional_kwargs)


class DeferredCall(object, metaclass=DeferredCallMetaclass):
    """Call that is evaluated lazyly"""
    def __init__(self, func, *func_args, **func_kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.func_args = func_args
        self.func_kwargs = func_kwargs

    def resolve(self):  # called by JSON encoder
        return self.func(*self.func_args, **self.func_kwargs)
```

Then:

```python
instance1 = DeferredCall( lambda x: x, 3)
instance2 = DeferredCall( lambda x, y, z: z, 2, 3, z=4)
print("instance1 + 1          ->", instance1 + 1)
print("2 ** instance1         ->", 2 ** instance1)
print("instance1 > instance2  ->", instance1 > instance2)
print("instance1 >= instance2 ->", instance1 >= instance2)
print("instance1 <= instance2 ->", instance1 <= instance2)
print("instance1 != instance2 ->", instance1 != instance2)
```

Outputs:

> ```
> instance1 + 1          -> 4
> 2 ** instance1         -> 8
> instance1 > instance2  -> False
> instance1 >= instance2 -> False
> instance1 <= instance2 -> True
> instance1 != instance2 -> True
> ```